# Errors while building a project in omnet++

Tags: c++, c++14, omnet++

While building of an imported project, an errors occurs. I am using gcc Version 9.

I have already built Inet 4.1 successfully. I also tried this with some other gcc Version between 5 and 8, but the same errors occured.

```
main.cc
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62,
                 from /home/sebastian/Downloads/omnetpp-5.4.1/include/omnetpp.h:29,
                 from main.cc:20:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/uniform_int_dist.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::uniform_int_distribution<double>’:
model/Showcase/Layer1/DummyWindPark/WindPowerGenerator.h:53:43:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:60:49: error: static assertion failed: template argument must be an integral type
   60 |       static_assert(std::is_integral<_IntType>::value,
      |                                                 ^~~~~
In file included from model/Showcase/Layer1/Windpark/WindParkNetwork.h:21,
                 from model/Showcase/Layer1/SmartParkingScenario.h:26,
                 from main.cc:26:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, or whoever wrote the header file `model/Showcase/Layer1/DummyWindPark/WindPowerGenerator.h`,
is attempting in that file to instantiate the template [`template< class IntType = int >class uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)
with `IntType` = `double`, as the compiler notes:

```
In instantiation of ‘class std::uniform_int_distribution<double>’
```

`double` is not an integral type, and the template contains a [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_assert)
requiring that `IntType` *is* an integral type. So that `static_assert` fails as compiletime:

```
 error: static assertion failed: template argument must be an integral type
```

Integral types are are those that satisfy the template predicate [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral).

If you or the author of the failing `std::uniform_int_distribution<double>` want to generate
a uniform distribution of `double` then they should use [`template< class RealType = double > class uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)